# In Visual Studio, change work item state when dragging to "In Progress"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to automatically have the state of a work item be changed to something appropriate like "Active" when dragging it from your available workitems to the in progress work-field?

It would save the work of manually opening the workitems whenever you start working on them, just to set the status, and then adding them to the "in progress work" anyways.

**EDIT**

I am talking about the visual studio tfs explorer! thanks for editing my post so that it doesn't reflect that anymore! (sarcasm)

[image]

Comment: LOL - Person flippantly changes the topic... misspells "Change"

Comment: It already updates the work item's state, when you drag the work item to the "In Progress Work". Isn't it happening for you?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify so I'm going to make some assumptions.  I'll assume you're using TFS 2013 and the Scrum Process Template.  I'm not sure if you're talking about dragging items around on the Kanban board, or the Task Board.  The way you configure each of those boards is different.

For the Kanban board you can map columns to WI states using the built in UI.  Just click Customize columns, then you have the name of the columns at the top, and the WI state they map to at the bottom:

[image]
[image]

For the Task Board you need to use the witadmin.exe command-line tool, you execute witadmin exportprocessconfig, modify the xml file, then do a witadmin importprocessconfig to upload the changes.  The relevant section you need to change is the TaskBacklog section which maps taskboard columns to WI states:

[image]

Comment: Wasn't talking about the web access or kanban board, was talking about visual studio, but thanks anyways.